# $P(s)=1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(s)}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(2s)}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(4s)}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(8s)}-...}}}}$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, journals

[Vassilev-Missana - A note on prime zeta function and Riemann zeta function](http://nntdm.net/volume-22-2016/number-4/12-15)¹ claims the following remarkable identity:
$$
P(s)=1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(s)}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(2s)}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(4s)}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(8s)}-...}}}},
$$
for integer $s>1$, where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function defined as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$ and $P(s)$ denotes the prime zeta function $\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}^\infty \frac{1}{p^s}$, and $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of prime numbers.

I am not a number theoretician, but the paper looks like it might contain some errors. I have already raised the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570344/proving-an-identity-involing-the-riemann-zeta-function), and it looks like I may be right. However, after performing some calculations using Wolfram Alpha, it looks like the identity might have some truth to it.

If we denote by $\epsilon(s)$ the error term $P(s)-\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(s)}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(2s)}-...}}\right)$, we get the following results for successive finite approximations to the nested radical, in which the $k^{\rm th}$ approximation is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(s)}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(2s)}-\sqrt{...-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(2^{k-1}s)}}}}}$, and in this case by taking $s=2$:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
k & \epsilon(2)\\ \hline
3 &  0.19732\ldots \\ \hline
4 &  -0.13198\ldots \\ \hline
6 &  0.04839\ldots \\ \hline
5 &  -0.035665\ldots \\ \hline
7 &  0.007512\ldots \\ \hline
8 & -0.013753\ldots \\ \hline
9 & -0.00304\ldots \\ \hline
\end{array}

so indeed it looks like $\epsilon(2)$ is converging to $0$ (note the expression "*looks like*", as I have not run any calculations for *really* large $k$).

Additionally, by taking $s=3$ the identity above would remarkably imply that:

$$
\zeta(3) = 2\left((1-P(3))^2+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(6)}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(12)}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(24)}-...}}}\right)^{-1},
$$

and indeed taking the finite nested radical approximation for $k=9$, the error term is already $\epsilon=-0.002516\ldots$ and seems to approach $0$ as $k\to\infty$ (note again the expression "*seems to*").

Is it possible that the identity still holds, nonwithstanding the issues in the paper, and if so, how may one prove it? Or do the approximations for  large $k$ actually **not** produce $\epsilon\to0$? If so, how can the apparent convergence be explained?

---

¹ Note that the journal in question is a reputed one, with **Paul Erdős** being at some point the editor (between '95 and '96), not a second-rate journal.

Comment: Can the person who downvoted please explain their reason? I am just trying to understand the result of a published paper in a known mathematics journal...

Comment: some more entries to the table for $\epsilon(2)$, starting from $k=9$ and running through $k=17$: -0.00304495, -0.00837965, -0.00570749, -0.00704236, -0.00637463, -0.00670842, -0.0065415, -0.00662496, -0.00658323  --- if there is a convergence to zero, it is very slow...

Comment: The paper is simply wrong.  It claims the identity (Theorem 1) $(1-P(s))^2 =2/\zeta(s) - 1 + P(2s)$, where $P(s) = \sum p^{-s}$.  However $1/\zeta(s) = \sum \mu(n) n^{-s}$  whereas all the other terms in the identity involve only primes and products of two primes (including squares of primes).  Any number that is a product of three or more primes gives a contradiction to the stated result -- e.g. $30$.

Comment: In fact, in the claimed identity (7), the terms $1/(pqr)^s$ clearly appear in the LHS and do not in the RHS.

Comment: We have discussed yesterday that the pdf is pure nonsense. Why do you ask on MO ?

Comment: I once downloaded an article from that journal and it was also pure nonsense. Then I looked at the editorial board and there were a couple of names that explained a lot of its low quality...

Comment: @EFinat-S How did a journal once edited by Paul Erdos sink this low?

Comment: @reuns Although it is clear by now that your opinion was correct, IMHO the answer of an anonymous user to an anonymous user that asks for a judgement of validity of a signed article, published on a known journal, should consist on more objective claims than a generic "pure nonsense".

Comment: I just stumbled upon this paper and it caught me by surprise because five years ago I made the same error in my reasoning and derived the same formula. I had posted about it way back then in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346637/prime-zeta-function-proof-help-why-are-these-expressions-not-equal

Comment: "a journal once edited by Paul Erdos"   it seems that since 2004 this journal is no longer indexed by MathSciNet.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This has been answered in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288847/ps-1-sqrt-frac2-zetas-sqrt-frac2-zeta2s-sqrt-frac2-zeta#comment715366_288847) by [Lucia](https://mathoverflow.net/users/38624/lucia). The identity $$P(s)=1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(s)}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(2s)}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(4s)}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(8s)}-\cdots}}}}$$ is false. By subtracting $1$ from both sides and squaring, we have that $$(1-P(s))^{2}+1-\frac{2}{\zeta(s)}=1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(2s)}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(4s)}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\zeta(8s)}-\cdots}}},$$ which by the identity implies that $$(1-P(s))^{2}+1-\frac{2}{\zeta(s)}=P(2s).$$ This equation, which appears as theorem $1$ in the paper, is not true.

Comment: Maybe mark as CW to avoid reputation from Lucia's answer?

Comment: @LSpice Done.$ $

Comment: Maybe Lucia should have put the answer in an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 14):

This so-called "functional equation"
$$(1-P(s))^{2}+1-\frac{2}{\zeta(s)}=P(2s)$$
which was published in a [2016 paper](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-22/NNTDM-22-4-12-15.pdf) has been used in a [2019 paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00747680/file/GeneralizedRiemannHypothesis.pdf) claiming to prove the generalized Riemann hypothesis. As all here have pointed out, that equation is false. A disproof has been recently published in 2021 and can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.09418.pdf).  It interested me to discover this, because in 2015 I had derived this same false equation. You can find my posts about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346637/prime-zeta-function-proof-help-why-are-these-expressions-not-equal) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2322920/how-good-is-this-prime-zeta-function-approximation?noredirect=1&lq=1). I wanted to take it upon myself to show a generalization that highlights the error.

There is a formula that relates the partial euler prouct to the partial prime zeta function.

$$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{{p_k}^s}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^n\sum_{\{r\}}\prod_{j=1}^l\frac{(-1)^{i_j}}{i_j!}\left(\frac{{P_n(s\cdot r_j)}}{r_j}\right)^{i_j}$$

where the sum is over partitions of $r$ and $P_n(s)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{{p_k}^s}$, the partial prime zeta function. $p_*\in\text{Primes}$ (Note: this formula holds if we use any set of real numbers, not just the primes). For more details see Grunberg's paper [On asymptotics, Stirling numbers, Gamma function, and polylogs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0607514v1.pdf)

An equivalent representation is

$$
\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{{p_k}^s}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^n{\frac{B_k(-0!P_n(s),-1!P_n(2s),\dots,-(k-1)!P_n(ks))}{k!}}
$$

where $B_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is the complete [exponential Bell polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials).

On a separate note, this also is equal to the analytic form, $\exp{\left(-\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{P_n(ks)}
{k}}\right)}$

This means we can write

$$
\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s}}\right)
&=1-P_1\left(s\right)
\\
&=\color{red}{1-P_1\left(s\right)}\underbrace{\color{red}{-\frac{P_1\left(2s\right)}{2}+\frac{P_1\left(s\right)^{2}}{2}}}_0
\\
&=1-P_1\left(s\right)\underbrace{-\frac{P_1\left(2s\right)}{2}+\frac{P_1\left(s\right)^{2}}{2}}_0\space\underbrace{-\space\frac{P_1\left(3s\right)}{3}+\frac{P_1\left(2s\right)P_1\left(s\right)}{2}-\frac{P_1\left(s\right)^{3}}{6}}_0
\\
&=\cdots
\\
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{s}}\right)
&=\color{red}{1-P_2\left(s\right)-\frac{P_2\left(2s\right)}{2}+\frac{P_2\left(s\right)^{2}}{2}}
\\
&=1-P_2\left(s\right)-\frac{P_2\left(2s\right)}{2}+\frac{P_2\left(s\right)^{2}}{2}\underbrace{-\frac{P_2\left(3s\right)}{3}+\frac{P_2\left(2s\right)P_2\left(s\right)}{2}-\frac{P_2\left(s\right)^{3}}{6}}_0
\\
&=\cdots
\\
\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{s}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5^{s}}\right)
&=1-P_3\left(s\right)-\frac{P_3\left(2s\right)}{2}+\frac{P_3\left(s\right)^{2}}{2}-\frac{P_3\left(3s\right)}{3}+\frac{P_3\left(2s\right)P_3\left(s\right)}{2}-\frac{P_3\left(s\right)^{3}}{6}
\\
&=\cdots
\end{align}
$$

and so on.

In my case, I derived those lines with the red RHS in a different way and falsely assumed that the number of terms in the product on the LHS, as well as the number of summands in the partial prime zeta functions on the RHS could be continued beyond two terms. This is where the Riemann zeta function and the so-called "functional equation" came from.

These equations are true for any set of real numbers not just powers of primes starting from $2$. That's why as Lucia notes that the 2016 “identity” is true only if the Riemann zeta (as an Euler product) and the prime zeta functions involve a single prime term or two prime terms.

Thus a true generalized identity analogous to the false one is

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)=1-\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)-\frac{\left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}\right)}{2}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)^{2}}{2}$$

from which we can derive the nested radical identity

$$1-\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}=\\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{2\left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)-\sqrt{2\left(1-\frac{1}{a^{2}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{b^{2}}\right)-\cdots-\sqrt{2\left(1-\frac{1}{a^{2^n}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{b^{2^n}}\right)-1}}}$$

Comment: That is amazing! Thanks for this interesting remark.

Comment: @tryobrien. The last identity blew my mind